# Java java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java

I am making a prime number generator. However, there is an error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at line 20 (where I put the number into the array). How can I fix that and why does it give me this error?

```
 public class Generator {
    int min;
    int max;
    int[] primes = new int[max];

    public Generator(int minimum, int maximum)    {
        min = minimum;
        max = maximum;
    }

    public void generate()  {
        int index = 0;
        for(int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            if(isPrime(i))  {
                primes[index] = i;
                index++;
            }
        }
    }


    private boolean isPrime(int n)   {
        for(int i = 2; i < n; i++)  {
            if(n % i == 0)  {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int[] get()  {
        return primes;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is value of max in your program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you instantiate `Generator` class

```
int max; // max become 0
int[] primes = new int[max]; // then size of array become zero
```

Then there is not index `0` for size zero array.

You can initialize your array inside the constructor of `Generator` class

```
int min;
int max;
int[] primes
public Generator(int minimum, int maximum)    {
 min = minimum;
 max = maximum;
 primes = new int[maximum];
}
```

Comment: just for my understanding static initializer block is executed first followed by the constructor followed by the instance variables right. so even if he initializes the arrray size in the instance vaiable section,max would have already been initialsed in the constructor. so primes would be set to the size of max.

Comment: @war_Hero no all variable set it's **default** value. In this case `0` for `int`.

Comment: True but inside the constructor the value would be set right to max and finally after the constructor is executed instance variables are executed next at that time max will be having a value which would be set to the size is of the array

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your array inside your constructor, since the class variables section is run first before you even create an instance of your Generator.